# Cannot Upload Binary in Xcode Due to Beta OS

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a beta version of Sierra and need to upload my app's binary to iTunesConnect. I do not have a recent time machine backup and I have no backup of El Capitan. Even if I did, I have 450GBs used and I think a restore would take forever.

Can I download Xcode on my wife's computer, copy my Xcode project folder over, archive a new version, and upload it to iTunesConnect? Or will I run into problem with provisioning profiles or some other issue?

Comment: You can archive it on your Mac, download Xcode to your Wife's Mac, and just use Application Loader to send the IPA directly.

Comment: @AndyIbanez I found the user guide on Application Loader, I'll give it a try. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do that, but you should genarate your `.Cer` file from `keychain` in your wife's `mac`, and generate your `provisioning profiles` again in `developer.apple.com` again using `.Cer` which is create by your wife's `mac`.  Attention: this step is prove using your wife's `mac` archive your `.ipa`, if the `.ipa` break the law, they can found you by the `mac`'s identifier.

And re-archive your `.ipa` file, upload to `itunes connect`, no matter use `Xcode` or `Application Loader`, all is ok.